# grunt --tasks error path.js:488 throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings')

Tags: node.js

my node is `v0.12.7`, and my grunt is `grunt-cli v0.1.13 grunt v0.4.5`.

the following is my dependencies in `package.json`.

```
"bower": "1.3.8",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower": "0.18.0",
    "grunt-cachebuster": "0.1.5",
    "grunt-check-dependencies": "0.3.1",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.13",
    "grunt-connect-proxy": "0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.3",
    "grunt-git-describe": "2.3.2",
    "grunt-karma": "0.10.1",
    "grunt-replace": "0.8.0",
    "grunt-requirejs": "0.4.2",
    "grunt-shell": "0.6.4",
    "grunt-version-copy-bower-components": "^0.1.11",
    "jasmine-core": "2.2.0",
    "karma": "0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.1.4",
    "karma-requirejs": "0.2.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.12",
    "load-grunt-config": "0.13.2",
    "path": "^0.11.14",
    "requirejs": "2.1.16",
    "shelljs": "0.3.0"
```

and the following is my `gruntfile.js`

```
  require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'tasks')
  })
```

I search many materials which told me someone have fixed it. Could anyone help me to look into it?

---

My error stacks is

```
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
  at Object.posix.join (path.js:488:13)
  at Object.file.exists (/Users/zwshao/REA/widgets_new/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:381:28)
  at task.loadTasks (/Users/zwshao/REA/widgets_new/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:371:18)
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Task.task.init (/Users/zwshao/REA/widgets_new/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:457:33)
  at Object.grunt.tasks (/Users/zwshao/REA/widgets_new/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:120:8)
  at Object.module.exports [as cli] (/Users/zwshao/REA/widgets_new/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/cli.js:38:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt:45:20)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
  at startup (node.js:129:16)
  at node.js:814:3
```